# Possible to utilize setter cross-class in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to access an objects setter from another class for a minesweeper game, and am unsure if it is actually possible.

Essentially I have a Board class which contains all the logic for setting up the board, and inside my main method I want to prompt the user to enter an int, which then communicates this value to `Board.setHealth()`.

My prompt in my main method (contained in `Mines.java`) is as follows

```
if (keyboard.nextInt() < 1) {
  throw new Exception("Number must be higher than 0!");
}
else health = keyboard.nextInt();
Board.setHealth(health);
```

in my `Board.java` constructor I am declaring 2 ints, `startHealth(1)` and `health(not yet defined)`

My board setHealth method is as follows

```
  public void setHealth(int health){
    this.health = health;
  }
```

Now, the error I'm getting currently is

`non-static method setHealth(int) cannot be referenced from a static context`.

My understanding is that I'm attempting to setHealth on an object which is not yet instantiated (which was an error I had during a different phase where I wasn't utilising a setter method), so how do I redesign my method to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... you are trying to call setHealth by using static way but you didn't declare it as static
You can use your code only if you declare your method in this way

```
  public static void setHealth(int health){
    this.health = health;
  }
```

But if you do it in this way, also healt should be static and static variables are common to all the instances of a class so it's not a good strategy

In your case in your main method you should do something like this

```
if (keyboard.nextInt() < 1) {
  throw new Exception("Number must be higher than 0!");
}
else health = keyboard.nextInt();
Board b = new Board();
b.setHealth(health);
```

I hope this can help

Comment: It is unable to use "this" link in static context

Comment: I know this is the reason i saied that also healt should be static and this is not a good strategy

Comment: But still your code doesn't work

Comment: the right code for me is the last one; the first was just a sample

Comment: This helped immensely, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have first instantiate your Board class by calling its constructor

```
Board board = new Board();
```

And then you can use this object to set the value

```
board.setHealth(health);
```

Your code will be

```
Board board = new Board();
if (keyboard.nextInt() < 1) {
  throw new Exception("Number must be higher than 0!");
}
else {
health = keyboard.nextInt();
    board.setHealth(health);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`main(String[] args)` is a `static` method and you can't use non-static variables/methods directly.

So you need to create an `instance` to access the non-static members like below:

```
Board board = new Board();
board.setHealth(health);
```

**static members are meant to be used at class level, you reference them using ClassName.method();**

For accessing non-static members, you need to create an instance/object (`Board board = new Board();`) first and then only be able to access like above using `objectReference.method();`

Please go through the below link for understanding more on static and non-static members:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

`Board` (with capital "B") is probably a `class`, not an object.
You probably wanted to create an `object` of this class

```
Board board = new Board();   // Maybe with some parameters in parenthesis
```

and then use

```
board.setHealth(health);
```

Comment: It is java question, not python one